# Has the /sys/bus/usb/ the same structure in all Linux distributions

Tags: linux, usb, serial-port

I am porting mono app from Windows to Linux. The app communicates with external board. This board is visible as three virtual serial ports. Every plays a different role.

The app is automatically detecting those ports. Can I relay on the structure and information in the `/sys/bus/usb/` ie are they the same in the different Linux distros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on the structure in `/sys/bus/usb/` to be identical across distributions, because it only relies on the kernel, and it's mature enough so it's unlikely to change in future kernel versions (but who knows...).

However, this is the wrong approach to solve your problem. The correct approach is to include a custom `udev` rule with your app, and make sure this `udev` rule is copied to the proper place (usually `/etc/udev/rules.d`, but that may depend on the distro. In doubt, let the user configure it) during installation. The `udev` rule can then assign symbolic linkes (similar to those you see in `/dev/disks`) to the three serial devices, using whatever information (e.g. vendor/device id) identifies your board uniquely. Your applications should use the symbolic links.

In a pinch, you can also use the usb-tree structure you were planning to use for the ryle. See `udevadm info --attribute-walk ...` for a list of properties available for your devices.

Comment: I do it this way as the device is used by the people with no IT knowledge so I try to make it "configuration free". `so it's unlikely to change in future kernel versions (but who knows...).` if they change it I will change the app :)

Comment: People with no IT knowledge using Linux should still understand how to use the package system on their distro, and usually the packages have install scripts. You didn't say *which* information from `/sys/bus/usb` you plan to use, but you should also keep in mind that the enumeration of root hubs is not guaranteed to stay identical across boots.

Comment: I iterate through all devices and search for my PID, VID and interface numbers (it is composite device)